# WP8 Progress Bar Not Rendering

Tags: windows-phone-8, grid, progress-bar, longlistselector

I have placed a `Progress Bar` control within my MainPage.xaml. The application type is `Pivot`.

For some reason, the `Progress Bar` **and** a `TextBlock` which I have placed within a `PivotItem` and below a `Grid` are not showing. There is a `LongListSelector` directly beneath these two controls. Are these two controls not showing because of that? I used the UI to drag the `LongListSelector` beneath then anyway, so I'm not sure why it's not showing.

This is the XAML:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="Title" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
    <!--Pivot item one-->
    <phone:PivotItem Header="Header" Foreground="Black">
        <Grid>
            <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Value="0" IsIndeterminate="True" Margin="0,0,0,579"/>
            <TextBlock Name="txtLastUpdated" FontWeight="Black" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,24,0,541" />
            <phone:LongListSelector Name="llsLocations" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged" Margin="0,62,0,0">
                <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                ...
                ...
                ...
```

As you can see, there is a ProgressBar and a TextBlock above the `LongListSelector` who are also inside the `Grid` control.

Any ideas why these two controls are not showing?

Comment: Can you try to use the progressbar without the textblock and the LLS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have something wrong with Margin or item positioning. I've tested code below and it works:

```
<phone:Pivot Title="Title" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
  <!--Pivot item one-->
  <phone:PivotItem Header="Header" Foreground="Black">
     <Grid>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
           <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Value="0" IsIndeterminate="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
           <TextBlock Name="txtLastUpdated" FontWeight="Black" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Something"/>
         </StackPanel>
         <phone:LongListSelector Name="llsLocations" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged" Margin="0,62,0,0"/>
     </Grid>
 </phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove margin of all child element of StackPanel. This will defiantly helps you. 

<phone:Pivot Title="Title" Background="White" Foreground="Black">
  <!--Pivot item one-->
 <phone:PivotItem Header="Header" Foreground="Black">
  <Grid>
   <StackPanel>
   <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Value="0" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
   <TextBlock Name="txtLastUpdated" FontWeight="Black" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black"  />
   <phone:LongListSelector Name="llsLocations" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged" >
       <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
   </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
  </phone:PivotItem>
</<phone:Pivot>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hardcoding control's position (especially by dragging controls in designer) is not a good practice. Try to define rows for your Grid, then specify Grid.Row for controls inside the Grid. With that you can arrange Grid content more neatly. Check this [link](http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html) for more sample and explanation about layouting controls inside Grid. Following is an example for your situation :

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Header" Foreground="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <ProgressBar Name="progressBar" Value="0" IsIndeterminate="True" />
            <TextBlock Name="txtLastUpdated" FontWeight="Black" FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" />
        </StackPanel>
        <phone:LongListSelector Grid.Row="1" Name="llsLocations" ItemsSource="{Binding}" SelectionChanged="LongListSelector_OnSelectionChanged" >
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        ...
        ...
```